# Filtering 1D numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

**Explanation:**

I have two numpy arrays: dataX and dataY, and I am trying to filter each array to reduce the noise. The image shown below shows the actual input data (blue dots) and an example of what I want it to be like(red dots). I do not need the filtered data to be as perfect as in the example but I do want it to be as straight as possible. I have provided sample data in the code. 
[image]

**What I have tried:**

Firstly, you can see that the data isn't 'continuous', so I first divided them into individual 'segments' ( 4 of them in this example), and then applied a filter to each 'segment'. Someone suggested that I use a [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter). The full, run-able code is below:

```
import scipy as sc
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample Data
ydata = np.array([1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,7,6,8,6,8,6,6,8,6,6,8,6,6,7,6,5,5,6,6, 10,11,12,13,12,11,10,10,11,10,12,11,10,10,10,10,12,12,10,10,17,16,15,17,16, 17,16,18,19,18,17,16,16,16,16,16,15,16])
xdata = np.array([1,2,3,1,5,4,7,8,6,10,11,12,13,10,12,13,17,16,19,18,21,19,23,21,25,20,26,27,28,26,26,26,29,30,30,29,30,32,33, 1,2,3,1,5,4,7,8,6,10,11,12,13,10,12,13,17,16,19,18,21,19,23,21,25,20,26,27,28,26,26,26,29,30,30,29,30,32])

# Used a diff array to find where there is a big change in Y. 
# If there's a big change in Y, then there must be a change of 'segment'.
diffy = np.diff(ydata)

# Create empty numpy arrays to append values into
filteredX = np.array([])
filteredY = np.array([])

# Chose 3 to be the value indicating the change in Y
index = np.where(diffy >3)

# Loop through the array
start = 0
for i in range (0, (index[0].size +1) ):
# Check if last segment is reached
    if i == index[0].size:
        print xdata[start:]
        partSize = xdata[start:].size
# Window length must be an odd integer
        if partSize % 2 == 0:
            partSize = partSize - 1

        filteredDataX = sc.signal.savgol_filter(xdata[start:], partSize, 3)
        filteredDataY = sc.signal.savgol_filter(ydata[start:], partSize, 3)
        filteredX = np.append(filteredX, filteredDataX)
        filteredY = np.append(filteredY, filteredDataY)

    else:
        print xdata[start:index[0][i]]
        partSize = xdata[start:index[0][i]].size
        if partSize % 2 == 0:
            partSize = partSize - 1
        filteredDataX = sc.signal.savgol_filter(xdata[start:index[0][i]], partSize, 3)
        filteredDataY = sc.signal.savgol_filter(ydata[start:index[0][i]], partSize, 3)
        start = index[0][i] 
        filteredX = np.append(filteredX, filteredDataX)
        filteredY = np.append(filteredY, filteredDataY)

# Plots
plt.plot(xdata,ydata, 'bo', label = 'Input Data')
plt.plot(filteredX, filteredY, 'ro', label = 'Filtered Data')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Result')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is my result:
[image]
When each point is connected, the result looks as follows.
[image]
I have played around with the order, but it seems like a third order gave the best result.

I have also tried these filters, among a few others:

- [scipy.signal.medfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html)
- [scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html)

But so far none of the filters I have tried were close to what I really wanted. What is the best way to filter data such as this? Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get something looking close to your ideal would be clustering + linear regression.

Note that you have to provide the number of clusters and I also cheated a bit in scaling up `y` before clustering.[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import cluster, stats

ydata = np.array([1,0,1,2,1,2,1,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,7,6,8,6,8,6,6,8,6,6,8,6,6,7,6,5,5,6,6, 10,11,12,13,12,11,10,10,11,10,12,11,10,10,10,10,12,12,10,10,17,16,15,17,16, 17,16,18,19,18,17,16,16,16,16,16,15,16])
xdata = np.array([1,2,3,1,5,4,7,8,6,10,11,12,13,10,12,13,17,16,19,18,21,19,23,21,25,20,26,27,28,26,26,26,29,30,30,29,30,32,33, 1,2,3,1,5,4,7,8,6,10,11,12,13,10,12,13,17,16,19,18,21,19,23,21,25,20,26,27,28,26,26,26,29,30,30,29,30,32])

def split_to_lines(x, y, k):
    yo = np.empty_like(y, dtype=float)
    # get the cluster centers and the labels for each point
    centers, map_ = cluster.vq.kmeans2(np.array((x, y * 2)).T.astype(float), k)
    # for each cluster, use the labels to select the points belonging to
    # the cluster and do a linear regression
    for i in range(k):
        slope, interc, *_ = stats.linregress(x[map_==i], y[map_==i])
        # use the regression parameters to construct y values on the
        # best fit line
        yo[map_==i] = x[map_==i] * slope + interc
    return yo

import pylab
pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'or')
pylab.plot(xdata, split_to_lines(xdata, ydata, 4), 'ob')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thank you for taking the time to answer :) I just have a few questions: Do you always need to scale up Y or is it only specific to this case? If so, how do I know how much to scale it by ? I am currently reading up on clustering, but it seems a bit complicated. Do you mind adding on comments to your code to explain briefly what each line in the "split_to_lines" function does?

Comment: @user3451660 clustering is as far as I know---and I am no expert---not an exact science. But I think it works best when the clusters are kind of roundish. Now, in your data, the clusters are elongated in `x` direction, so I stretched `y` as a quick fix. Sorry I can't be more specific. I'll see what I can do about the commenting

Comment: Ok, thank you! So technically only the Ydata is being filtered ? If I had to connect each point, (see additional image added) my original shows X increasing until there is a big decrease in X, whereas yours is slightly different. Also, with your method, I would also need to calculate how many lines there are to split (there were 4 in the example but could be many more)?

Comment: @user3451660 Yes and yes. But you can simply sort the points within each cluster.